# How can I get low-level raw bytes API starting from IRedisClientsManager?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

When I use the following code:

```
using(var client=new RedisClient()){
    client.Hset()
}
```

all the low-level raw bytes API are available.

But when I change the code to:

```
IRedisClientsManager redis= new PooledRedisClientManager();
using(var client=redis.GetClient()){
    client.?
}
```

then none of the low-level raw bytes API are available. I'm using ioc and IRedisClientsManager is my only choice.

Would anybody pls show me how I can get it done?

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast it to `IRedisNativeClient` or `RedisNativeClient`, i.e:

```
var redisManager = new PooledRedisClientManager();
using(var redis = redisManager.GetClient()){
    var rawRedis = (RedisNativeClient)redis;
}
```